# Python Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

Hey all, I'm unable to understand some part of the following code (from **Programming Python** by **Mark Lutz**):

```
import _thread as thread

stdoutmutex = thread.allocate_lock()
exitmutexes = [thread.allocate_lock() for i in range(10)]

def counter(myId, count):
    for i in range(count):
        stdoutmutex.acquire()
        print('[%s] => %s' % (myId, i))
        stdoutmutex.release()
    exitmutexes[myId].acquire()

# signal main thread
for i in range(10):
    thread.start_new_thread(counter, (i, 100))

for mutex in exitmutexes:
    while not mutex.locked(): pass
print('Main thread exiting.')
```

I'm using Python3. Well, I'm able to understand the **stdoutmutex** thing and how it works, but I'm unable to understand how the above code processes **exitmutexes** list, because the individual locks in **exitmutexes** have been acquired, but not released. Once all the 10 threads have started, how do the below 3 lines work? The author has described this as a way of going without using time.sleep()

```
for mutex in exitmutexes:
        while not mutex.locked(): pass
    print('Main thread exiting.')
```

Comment: Does the acquisition of a lock keep a thread alive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically waits until all exit mutexes have been locked and then exits.

```
for mutex in exitmutexes:
    while not mutex.locked(): pass
```

This code iterates over the exit mutexes and for each mutex it enters a loop waiting for the mutex to be locked.

However, it uses "active waiting" resulting in very high CPU usage (like an endless loop doing nothing) which is a very bad thing.